# How we can add more then one plugins in class path of kafka connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How we can add more then one plugins externally in kafka connect ???
https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/tutorial/debezium-with-oracle-jdbc/Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

You don't add it to the `CLASSPATH`, you use `plugin.path` to point to the folder(s) that contain the plugin JARs.

You can see more information here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#installing-plugins

Answer (score 0):

Used below steps :

1 Added new folder like below in docker 
https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/blob/master/unwrap-smt/debezium-jdbc-es/Dockerfile#L3

2 Added same folder in class path

3 Downloaded custom plugin and using docker volume mount added provided that to docker container

I am able to get plugin in plugin list api